# Pass PHP Variables from one plugin file to another WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, paypal

I am working on a WordPress plugin and have run into a little road block. I am working on a part of the script that interacts with PayPal's IPN. I have an ipn.php file that is in the plugin directory, that file gathers the response from PayPal and verifies all the transaction details.
That part works fine, but the second part of this is I must insert the variables into the WordPress database to mark a successful purchase. 
Since $wpdb is not available in the ipn.php file, I must pass the data to the core of the plugin for processing.

I am open to other solutions on this and your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is an example, this file will be used for a $.load() to fill an area in the admin panel

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $promos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."voltbam_promocodes");

    foreach($promos as $promo){
        ?>
            ID: <?php echo $promo->id ?><br />
            Name: <?php echo $promo->name ?><br />
            Value: <?php echo $promo->value ?><br />
            Type: <?php echo $promo->type ?><br /><br />

        <?
    }

?>
```

And here is the output

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in (filename) on     line 3
```

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like you are making some incorrect assumptions.  What do you mean by *Since $wpdb is not available in the ipn.php file,...* ??  It's my understanding that `$wpdb` is global in wordpress, which means in order to use it in a function you need to just insert the statement `global $wpdb;` at the top of the function.  Right?  Of course you need to reference that var only after it has been initialized, but that shouldn't be a problem.  The real title of this question should be:  "How can I modify the WP DB within a plugin?" And to do that, reference the global `$wpdb`.

Comment: That does not seem to be working. I will update my post with the code that I am working with and the output.

Comment: It sounds like he's set up PayPal to call 'ipn.php' for IPN processing, so it's not going through WordPress at all, even though the file is in the plugin directory.  That's why $wpdb isn't available.

Comment: @Mike Fulton - ahh, well if that's the case, what I suggested won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring `../../../wp-load.php` will bring the WordPress core in and give you access to the $wpdb global. This is usually three directories above you, but it may be more if your script is in a further subdirectory.

If you're on a multisite installation, make sure that $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] matches the URL of the WordPress site that you want to access, before requiring wp-load.php.

Comment: Can I be certain that my plugin will always be in the same place on all installations? I have not yet implemented wordpress multisite support.

Comment: The WordPress plugins directory is always in the same place relative to the rest of the installation, whether it is multisite or not.

Answer (score 1):

In my own setup, all the IPN handling code is in my plugin. I have a shortcode that calls it when needed.

I created a custom page template that is stripped of most everything but the basic post loop. This page is never shown to the user, so none of the display oriented stuff matters. Then I created a page called 'ipnhandler' based on that template, with just the shortcode as the content.

I've got this page set as the IPN handler with PayPal. Because it's a regular page, there's no links into the WordPress folders or anything like that.  Just this:

http://www.mysite.com/ipnhandler

When PayPal calls this page, Wordpress sees the shortcode and calls my plugin, which does the required IPN processing.

Comment: This is a pretty cool idea. If I could mark more than one answer I would mark this one too.

Comment: I am pretty new to Stackoverflow so I dunno if you can change your "best answer" selection, but you **could** click the up-arrow!  ;^)

Comment: Technically this is not the "best" answer for me because I have a lot of it already written, so I up-voted it and will keep it in mind for future projects. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

Either submit your ajax requests to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` or `include 'wp-load.php';` I personally suggest `admin-ajax.php`. See [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: He's not making AJAX calls. He's telling PayPal to open a particular URL when they have an instant payment notification message.

I don't think you really want them calling something in the middle of your WordPress setup.

Comment: The OP specifically states he's using `$.load()`